# Referencing a Price List- Bukkit Plugin

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I am new to java and have just recently started programming Bukkit plugins for practice. I am currently trying to make a plugin that allows a user to use the command-line to buy almost any item. Currently I am working on the "price check" command. I have it where it'll locate the item in org.bukkit.Material and it'll then spit out what it found using a sender.sendMessage(); line. I have a price-list that I need the code to reference and then display the buy and sell prices. Here is an example of of the price list:

```
NAME: BUY SELL
STONE: 1 1
GRASS: 1 1
DIRT: 1 1
COBBLESTONE: 1 1
WOOD: 2 2
SAPLING: 5 5
BEDROCK: 1 1
WATER: 250 250
STATIONARY_WATER: 250 250
LAVA: 1 1
STATIONARY_LAVA: 1 1
SAND: 1 1
```

I realize that Essentials Econ has it's own price list, and if that could be used instead, I am fine with that too, as long as what needs to be imported is listed as well as the example.
My code thus far is:

```
package me.rougelong.globalshop;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.plugin.PluginDescriptionFile;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import org.bukkit.Material;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class globalshop extends JavaPlugin{
public final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
public static globalshop plugin;

@Override
public void onDisable() {
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = this.getDescription();
    this.logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + "  Has Been Disabled!");
}

@Override
public void onEnable() {
    PluginDescriptionFile pdfFile = this.getDescription();
    this.logger.info(pdfFile.getName() + " Version " + pdfFile.getVersion() + "  Has Been Enabled!");
}


public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
    String itemName = args[0];
    //String amount = args[1];
    if (args.length > 4 && commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("shopcheck")) {
           sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Too many arguments! /shopcheck [item_name] [quantity]");
           return false;
        } 
    if (args.length < 1 && commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("shopcheck")) {
           sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Not enough arguments! /shopcheck [item_name] [quantity]");
           return false;
        }

    if (commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("shopcheck")){
        Material data = Material.matchMaterial(itemName);
        if(null == Material.matchMaterial(itemName)) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Not Found, not sellable, spelled wrong, etc!" + data);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "It is... " + data);
            //SUGGESTED CODE GOES HERE TO DISPLAY PRICE
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

}
```

So, my question restated is: How would I format the list so that java could reference it?
And what code could I use to extract the correct prices?

Thanks for the help.

**EXTRA**
I am going to add commands to change the prices from in game. So if you have the time and the will, I wouldn't mind seeing an example of that code. Thanks.

Comment: Bukkit provides plugins with a `Logger` of their own, please use that instead of Minecraft's `Logger`. It makes it easier for you and any possible plugin consumers to find relevant log messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Make sure you have a config.yml

inside your *JavaPlugin* (or with a instance of it) you can invoke the *saveConfig()* method which will save your config.yml (will also create the config.yml if one is not already made).

```
//inside the main class
this.saveConfig();

//or with an instance
somePluginInstance.saveConfig();
```

### Add values to the config.yml

Next you can go ahead and set values inside the config.yml:

```
int BUY = 1;//Buy value
int SELL = 1;//Sell value
String block = "cobble";
String buyAndSell = BUY+":"+SELL; //throw it into a string

//inside the main class
this.getConfig().set("pathToValues."+block, buyAndSell);//put the values inside the config

//with an instance
pluginInstance.getConfig().set("pathToValues"+, buyAndSell);//put the values inside the config
```

it is then required to save the config after you have made your changes to it

```
 //#### REQUIRED ####
    this.saveConfig();
    //or
    pluginInstance.saveConfig();
```

### Getting the values from the config.yml

we will now retrieve the values that we have set from before.

first we need to check if the config has the values we want. then we must split the two values apart. after that we can remove any non number that the user has put it and turn it into an integer that we can use.

```
String block = "cobble";

if(this.getConfig().contains("pathToValues."+block))
{
   String temp = this.getConfig().getString("pathToValues."+block);//Get the string that we set above

   String[] buyAndSellValues = temp.split(":");

   int Buy = Integer.parseInt(buyAndSellValues[0].replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));//replace all non numbers with blanks and turn it into an integer
   int Sell = Integer.parseInt(buyAndSellValues[1].replaceAll("[^\\d.]", ""));

   System.out.println("BUY: "+ Buy);
   System.out.println("SELL: "+Sell);
}
```

Enjoy.